# Python - How to use Multiprocessing in a for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

sorry in advance if there is any grammatical problems.

my bad if this is asked before, I've searched similar questions here on stackoverflow and couldn't find anything. I mean, i couldn't understand anything because im a beginner in python.
i've also watched some tutorials on youtube but it didn't really help me to solve my problems.

so my question is very simple, i have some for loops and i want to use multiprocessing to run these loops faster. how can i do it?

here is my code:

```
for x in list1:
    finalarray.append(x)
for x in list2:
    finalarray.append(x)
for x in list3:
    finalarray.append(x)
for x in tlist4:
    finalarray.append(x)
```

**how can i use multiprocessing to speed up this code?**

Comment: Can you pick a different example? You can't parallelize creating a list, but you can parallelize the computation of the values if it's intense, for example if you are testing if large numbers are prime.

Comment: @xjcl oh ok so i basically can't use multiprocessing for for loops?

Comment: You can use them to parallelize calculations, but you can't really parallelize creating a list like in your example, that's why I said can you use a different example